# sap-cloud-sdk-pipeline_How to configure multiple productive branches in config.yml file?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sap-cloud-sdk

I can trigger different branch for production deployment as I set it as productive branch in .pipeline/config.yml file as below: 
general:
  collectTelemetryData: false
  productiveBranch: 'develop'

Question: 
1. How I can set multiple branches as productive Branch in this file?
2. Is there a way for me to filter all feature branches from productive branch?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I would like to understand more about your use case. How are the different "productive branches" different? How is the branching model? We designed the pipeline for a continuous deployment model where you either work with PRs to one branch (be it called `master`, `trunk` or `develop`), or directly commit on this branch.

There are two potential solutions for question 1

First, you can set different values for productive branch on different branches in the pipeline config file. Those branches are then treated equally, so each push on one of those branches triggers a deployment. Of course this has implications for diffs and PRs between those branches.

Second, you might consider extending the production deployment stage via an [stage level extension](https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/extensibility/#1-extend-individual-stages). This provides more control over the workflow to you, you can fully customize the branch pattern you need, but it is more complex to do.

I don't understand your second question, but I think with what the pipeline has built in you can't do that. With an extension you're free to build whatever logic fits your purpose.

Please feel free to elaborate on your requirements. I can't promise anything, but we are always interested in understanding workflows we're not yet aware of to consider this in future design.

Kind regards